# Best practices for caching front page queries for Google App Engine (GAE)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

Wanted to ask what is the best practices for caching front pages queries for google app engine whose datastore provide only eventual consistency (unless ancestor queries are used)

The issue I'm running into is if I put an item into the datastore, I can't immediately run a query to get the correct and most up-to-date results and based on the docs I'm reading, there's no way for me to know when all the index values (or just the relevant ones) have been updated to produce the updated query

I've set up a manual add into the cache in parallel but then I would never really have a point of entry to make sure the cache is in sync with the datastore, unless I set an arbitrary time for cache expiry...

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache your query as usual, but in addition use _post_put_hook to invalidate current cached value. This way you will have *almost* up to date results in your cache.

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
  CACHE_KEY = 'bla_cache'
  bla = ndb.StringProperty()

  @clasmethod
  def build_page(cls):
    result = memcache.get(CACHE_KEY)
    if result is None:
      result = cls.query().fetch(100)
    return result

  def _post_put_hook(self, future):
    memcache.delete(CACHE_KEY)
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry! Do you know if the _post_put_hook is called after the entity put is completed or after the indexes are updated? If the former, there's a chance I may still be loading old query results in the cache on the next read (i.e. if indexes are still not updated)

Comment: A `get` (rather than query) always has strong consistency, so if you populate your cache using `get` results, they will be up-to-date.  I can't find a reference right now, but I believe outstanding writes are always applied before an entity `get` returns, to ensure that strong consistency.

Comment: _post_put_hook is after the put, but not after indexes are updated. Indexes are updated asynchronously by other services. You don't have visibility of the index update.

Comment: Got it, so I guess the only way to check if I have the latest query info is to see if the put item is in the query results